# Change text color dynamically when background changes (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image slider with text overlayed on it. I want to change the text color to either black or white depending on the theme of the image (light or dark).

I would like to manually specify the theme of the image as I don't want to over-complicate things. So for example it could work like this:

```
If imagetheme == 'light'
textcolor == #000
```

...and vice versa.

Comment: It's very hard to say anything without seeing the code for the slider.

Comment: I'm using anything slider with a modified style sheet: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a stylesheet that reacts to theme classes placed on the `<body>` element (e.g. `.light`). No mess.

Comment: I don't really follow. Basically, I want the image slides to have some sought of tag or property where I can specify the theme of the image (light or dark) and then when a new slide is activated, the text color changes based on the theme inputted.

Comment: @Emmanuel: [Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/r5CTK/) You can easily apply it to a particular element, as opposed to `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have almost written it yourself! I would do..

```
if ( var imagetheme == 'light' ) {
  var textcolor = '#000';
}
else if { var imagetheme == 'dark' ) {
  var textcolor = '#fff';
}
```

Or you could write it with Javascript's Ternary operator..

```
var imagetheme == 'light' ? var textcolor = '#000' : var textcolor = '#fff';
```

Comment: None of those are syntactically valid.